# Hibernate HQL Syntax error in exist clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have this hql query .

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
                    "select inv from Invoice inv " +
                            "where 1=1  " +
                            "and inv.edited = false  " +
                            "and businessSubscription.customer.user.id = :userId " +
                            "and inv.customerInvoice is null " +
                            "and inv.parentInvoice is null order by inv.id desc " +
                            "and exists (select 1 from InvoiceItem invItm where invItm.invoice.id = inv.id and invItm.product.id in (:productIdList))"
            );
```

Why receive this exception ?

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: and near line 1, column 228 [select inv from Invoice inv where 1=1  and inv.edited = false  and businessSubscription.customer.user.id = :userId and inv.customerInvoice is null and inv.parentInvoice is null order by inv.id desc and exists (select 1 from InvoiceItem invItm where invItm.invoice.id = inv.id and invItm.product.id in (:productIdList))]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
```

Where is syntax error ?
I think problem is on `invItm.invoice.id = inv.id`  , can use outside aliases in parentheses ?

Comment: Your HQL looks to have multiple problems.  Here is one of them: the `EXISTS` subquery should be comparing `inv` directly to `invItm.invoice.`  You need to compare entities, not columns.

Comment: excuse me , I confused , can you give me a example ?

Comment: Add your table and/or entity definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your receive this exception (`unexpected token: and near line 1, column 228`) because you have `and exists` after `order by inv.id desc`. Move `exists` into your where-clause (before `order by`).